# Perl FTP "GLOB" causes blank entries?

Tags: perl, ftp, glob

I have a perl script that is attempting to FTP files and it seems to be failing every other file.
I determined that for some reason the

```
$filename = glob $filename
```

is setting `$filename` to empty rather than the full filename.

I printed out the filename just before the glob line and it is correct and has no spaces in it.

I also tried just commenting out the glob line but then it returns "Not a GLOB reference" so apparently net ftp requires that.

Any idea what might cause glob to return empty? (and why it works on the first file and every 2nd file after that)

This is what I'm sending to the sub:

```
ftpToDevice($ftp,$device_dir,$config,$config,'put');
```

Here is the actual sub:

```
sub ftpToDevice {
        my ($ftp,$fileDir,$fileName,$fileNameDest,$action) = @_;
        print "ftp filename $fileName\n";
        $fileName =~ s/\s+//g;
        $fileNameDest =~ s/\s+//g;
        $fileName = glob($fileName);
        my $path = "cf3:\\";
        chdir $fileDir if $action eq 'put';                 

        print "file location: $fileDir/$fileName to $fileNameDest\n";

        if($ftp->cwd("$path")){
                if($action eq 'put'){
                        print "attempting FTP PUT $fileName $fileNameDest\n";
                        $ftp->put($fileName,$fileNameDest) or return "Error cannot put - " . $ftp->message;
                        #$ftp->rename($fileName,$fileNameDest) or return "Error cannot put - " . $ftp->message;
                } else {
                        print "Attempting to delete $path $fileNameDest\n";       
                        #$ftp->delete("$fileName") or return "Error cannot delete $fileName - " . $ftp->message;
                        $ftp->delete($fileNameDest) or return "Error cannot delete $fileName - " . $ftp->message;
                        print $ftp->message . "\n";
                }
        }
        chdir $masterDir if $action eq 'put';
        return 'success';
}
```

Comment: It's possible but unusual to use `glob` in scalar context, but assigning the file name it returns to the same variable you're passing as the pattern is really strange. And your mention of a glob reference error makes me wonder if you're confusing it with typeglobs. Need a [mcve], not one line of code.

Comment: I posed the code.

Comment: Why are you using `glob` for just one filename? What is the `$fileName` that is given to `glob` -- can you post an example of it?  (Is the function called over and over again, in a loop of some sort?)

Comment: An example is genericdevicename.cfg.  I dont actually know why 'glob' is used - that code is inherited from another person who originally wrote it.  The function is called by a foreach loop that provides the variables, including individual filename each time. However, if I try to just pass the 'fileName' without the glob, I get the 'Not a GLOB reference' error.

Comment: "_if I try to just pass the 'fileName' without the glob,_" -- to pass it where?  What gives that error,  "_not GLOB reference_"? That looks like something else, unrelated to `glob`.  // A `glob` used in scalar context, like `my $f = glob $p;`, has very particular behavior.  Every time it runs it returns the _next_ filename from an internal list built the first time it runs, wherever and whenever it is called in the program.  So something got broken in that regard, so it seems. We can only guess, or need more detail.

Comment: @zdim - if I take out the line where it says $fileName = glob($fileName) it gives that error.

I have been continuing to try and figure out why it wants a GLOB, it seems like a plain text file name should work here.  My guess is that something about how the $fileName variable is set is causing this.

I may have just found a solution, but not sure why it works.  I commented out the glob line, and instead used this:  $fileName = "". $fileName;  #is this converting it from something else to a 'string'?
With that, I was able to get the FTP to work on all of the files, not just every 2nd one.

Comment: The workaround you describe is baffling to me.  It does appear to turn it from something else to a valid filename but I don't at all see how that makes any sense. Again, do prints of `$fileName` show the correct filename?   Can you simplify the whole thing so to make sense posting it here?  (Or somebody has seen this before and they'll recognize it.)

Comment: I don't see which `ftp` library you use -- perhaps the `put` method can take _either_ a filename or a "GLOB reference" (filehandle), and if it's getting a name of a non-existing file it treats it as a glob ... and then finds out that it isn't?  (This is purely a guess.)  But I don't see how prepending an empty string could fix that.

Comment: @zdim if I print the fileName before the 'glob' line it prints correctly. If I print it after 'glob' it is blank.  I added all those prints to try and find what was going on.

I use just Net::FTP.

Comment: @zdim the workaround seems to work to get around whatever the issue is so I no longer need to even use 'glob'.  This is basically a copy of a script written by another guy a few years ago who has now retired.  I dont know why glob was ever used.

Comment: "_if I print the fileName before the 'glob' line it prints correctly._" -- are you sure? Could there be some control sequence attached, newline, a loose space ...?  (Btw, the code _removes_ spaces from filenames -- that would break those names!  If a file is called `a file.txt` and one removes spaces then you have `afile.txt` -- and there is no such file!  I'd suggest carefully rewriting this whole thing.

Comment: "_the workaround seems to work_" -- this is all very suspect (see my previous comment as well), and I would NOT use a "workaround" that I don't at all understand.  Who knows what else may get broken in some subtle intermittent way.  But of course it's your thing, you'll know what to do :)

Comment: (I've cleaned up some of my comments)

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution but am not sure why it worked.
I commented out the line:

```
$fileName = glob($fileName);
```

I added this instead:

```
$fileName = "" . $fileName;  #this converts it to a string I believe
```

This allowed all files to work (not just every second one) and did not give the GLOB error.

My theory is that somehow the list of files that is generated before the for each loop that uses the ftp sub is causing every second file to be a glob object (array or something?) rather than a plain text filename.

Comment: glob acts an interator in scalar context. It returns the first result the first time it's called, the second result the second time it's called, etc. It returns `undef` when there are no more results. The bug is called `glob` is scalar context.